# How to use childContextTypes in react with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to use childContextTypes like [this page](http://javascript.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/06/06/using-context-and-childcontext-in-react/)

I change it with `Typescript`:

```
import * as React from "react";

export class Parent extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    childContextTypes: {
        foo: string
    }

    getChildContext() {
        return { foo: "I m the grandparent" };
    }

    render() {
        return <Child />
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    context: any;

    static contextTypes: {
        foo: string
    }

    render() {
        return <div>Hello {this.context["foo"]}</div>;
    }
}
```

but I find nothing show in page!

Answer (score 1):

In classes, childContextTypes should be set using = instead of :

```
static childContextTypes = {
    foo: React.PropTypes.string
}
```